# TenssorFlow: fine tune Inception v3 for image classification

Tags: tensorflow

I am a newbie in TensorFlow.
I'm trying to fine tune the Inception v3 model by following the example on:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#Tuning

I have run he script:

```
python train_image_classifier.py \
--train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--dataset_name=flowers \
--dataset_split_name=train \
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
--model_name=inception_v3 \
--checkpoint_path=${PRETRAINED_CHECKPOINT_DIR}/inception_v3.ckpt \
--checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits \
--trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits \
--learning_rate=0.01 \
--learning_rate_decay_type=fixed \
--save_interval_secs=60 \
--save_summaries_secs=60 \
--log_every_n_steps=100 \
--weight_decay=0.00004
```

to generate model.ckpt-XXXX file.
How can I convert this file into pb file in oder to use it in the label_image example (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `model.ckpt` file only have checkpoint of variables but no `graph def`. Do you notice there is another file called `model-ckpt-xxxxx.meta`? That file has `graph def`.

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import meta_graph
from tensorflow.python.training import training_util

mg = meta_graph.read_meta_graph_file("model-ckpt-xxxxx.meta")
training_util.write_graph(mg.graph_def, "your/output/dir", "graph.pb", as_text=False)
```